# PDO prepare returns False whit sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I want to insert data to my database stored in SQLite but, when I pass my query to pdo prepare it's retruns false and giving me this message: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean.

Here is My PHP code:

```
$ql = "INSERT INTO customer_in (`ledger_id`, `daybook_id`, `description`, `amount`, `date`) VALUES (31, 141, '', 5000, '07/02/2018')";

try {
      $con = new Connection();
      $conn = $con->connect();
      $conn->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($q1);
      $results = $stmt->execute();
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
      // this is rolback fanction
      $conn->rollback();
      echo "query is not exe";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `$conn->prepare($q1);` returned FALSE. The problem is that you've named the query string as **$ql** instead of **$q1**, and then you called **$q1** in the code below it.

This code should work:

```
$q1 = "INSERT INTO customer_in (`ledger_id`, `daybook_id`, `description`, `amount`, `date`) VALUES (31, 141, '', 5000, '07/02/2018')";

try {
      $con = new Connection();
      $conn = $con->connect();
      $conn->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($q1);
      $results = $stmt->execute();
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
      // this is rolback fanction
      $conn->rollback();
      echo "query is not exe";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried and changed the name of my variable, but still it's not working and showing same error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean.